# Applying function to multiple rows using values from multiple rows

Tags: r, apply

I have created the following simple function in R:

```
fun    <- function(a,b,c,d,e){b+(c-a)*((e-b)/(d-a))}
```

That I want to apply this function to a `data.frame` that looks something like:

```
> data.frame("x1"=seq(55,75,5),"x2"=round(rnorm(5,50,10),0),"x3"=seq(30,10,-5))
  x1 x2 x3
1 55 51 30
2 60 45 25
3 65 43 20
4 70 57 15
5 75 58 10
```

I want to apply `fun` to each separate row to create a new variable `x4`, but now comes the difficult part (to me at least..): for the arguments d and e I want to use the values `x2` and `x3` from the next row. So for the first row of the example that would mean: `fun(a=55,b=51,c=30,d=45,e=25)`. I know that I can use `mapply()` to apply a function to each row, but I have no clue on how to tell mapply that it should use some values from the next row, or whether I should be looking for a different approach than `mapply()`?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: What about the last row? `a=75, b=58, c=10` and d and e are?

Comment: Good point! Let's say that `d=X2+2 (so 60)` and `e=0`. (For my project the last row is actually not of interest)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `mapply`, but shift the fourth and fifth columns by one row.  You can do it manually, or use `taRifx::shift`.

```
> dat
  x1 x2 x3
1 55 25 30
2 60 58 25
3 65 59 20
4 70 68 15
5 75 43 10
library(taRifx)
> shift(dat$x2)
[1] 58 59 68 43 25
> mapply( dat$x1, dat$x2, dat$x3, shift(dat$x2), shift(dat$x3) , FUN=fun )
[1]    25.00000 -1272.00000   719.00000   -50.14815    26.10000
```

If you want the last row to be NA rather than wrapping, use `wrap=FALSE,pad=TRUE`:

```
> shift(dat$x2,wrap=FALSE,pad=TRUE)
[1] 58 59 68 43 NA
```

Comment: sorry, but how is `shift(dat$x2)` (given it's the same x2 from OP's data) equal to what you've shown?

Comment: Thanks @Ari that does the trick! To address the problem with the last row I altered the code as follows: `dat$x4 <- mapply(dat$x1, dat$x2, dat$x3, c(shift(dat$x2,wrap=F),dat$x2[length(dat$x2)]+2), c(shift(dat$x3,wrap=F),0), FUN=fun)`

Comment: @Arun I didn't realize the OP used a random value in his data.frame construction, without specifying `set.seed()`, which is probably why at first glance it looked like the same as the OP's.  Added what my `dat` looks like.

Comment: The `embed` function may be another option for shifting the rows before passing to `mapply`.